# XML values not change after use setNodesValue

Tags: android, xml

I would like to change the values of RouteName node, according to the below code, I have studied some tutorials and applied it. Am I on the right way? what did I miss?

```
    try{
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Trip/"+tripID+".trip"));


        Node nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("RouteName").item(0);
        //newname is String variable which retrive value from edite text box
        nodes.setNodeValue(newname);

        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Trip/"+tripID+".trip"));
        transformer.transform(source, result);
     }

   catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Comment: i have update my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8984258/762919

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are writing/setting new value to dom object, which is not a physical file/document, if you want to reflect the changes to the filesystem, you need to write new contents on FileOutputStream.